# Can I make the Parameters Structure public with simulink embedded coder?

Tags: matlab, code-generation, simulink, embedded-coder

I am using Simulink Embedded Coder to generated C++ code of a model block. For my application, I need to access the P, ExtU, and ExtY structures.

Simulink Embedded Coder creates all 3 structures as private members of the class. ExtU and ExtY give me no problem, as there exists autogenerated Set/Get functions that allow me to pass values to ExtU and get values from ExtY. The problem is the P structure, which I must assign values to but is private.

I have tried different settings for storage class of the global parameters in
"Model Settings > Optimization > Configure (Default parameter behaviour: Tunable)"
but the structure remains a private.

Does anyone know if I can configure Embedded Coder to make the P structure public? Also, please share any other suggestion you may have to go around this problem.

Thanking in advance,
GGP